# Is there a way to set the lock screen to never lock?

Tags: functionality, lock-screen

Under Settings -> Lock Screen, the 'Screen times out after' drop down only gives me the option of 5 minutes maximum. I've seen posts online from some people who have similar phones and have the 'never' option in the dropdown. I have a Lumia 820 and I have no password enabled on the lock screen. Is there something that I've overlooked?

Comment: Strange! My 920 and 710 (Windows 7.1) both have options of 30 seconds, 1 minute, 3 minutes, 5 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes and never. And I have them both set to never.

Comment: It's not so strange. I'm using *Lumia 620 with GDR-3*. I just have only options up to 5 Minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings > Lock Screen > "Screen times out after" is the only place you can configure the lock screen timeout setting.

The times listed in the dropdown appear to vary by device and firmware version.

For example, I had a lend of a developer Lumia 920 from Nokia and it listed many timeout values including "never". Yet my own Lumia 920 (UK, unlocked) has less timeout options available doesn't include "never".

Comment: Is there any way to update the firmware?

Comment: @deutschZuid you'll have to contact a Nokia Care Center and see if they'll change the version of firmware you currently have - plus I don't know which versions have all the timeout options?