# How can I keep the screen always awake?

Tags: settings, windows-10-mobile, lumia-925, display, screen

How can I keep the screen of my Lumia 925 Windows 10 updated phone always awake?

The power button no longer works, so to turn on the screen I have to make a call or connect the charger.

**EDIT**

The [Tap to turn on](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA141946) feature does not work in my case. The reason may be the Windows 10 update. Now I have set the screen timeout to 5 minutes which is a semi-solution, but not good enough.

Comment: You can use double tap to turn on...

Comment: does this tap to turn on need a restart ? it is not working with my 925(windows 10 updated).

Answer (score 6):

Well, as I said **I would use double tap** to turn on the phone, I currently use it on L930 and I had used it before on a Lumia 925

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA141946

Also, I have searched your question and bellow is the answer:

[How can I make my Lumia 950 XL screen timeout after "never"?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/how-can-i-make-my-lumia-950-xl-screen-timeout-after-never)

[image: Lock Screen settings on my L930]
*My phone suports Timeout "Never" (Nunca in PT)*

**EDIT (answer to comment)**

"*how to switch Touch sensitivity to High. ? where is that settings ?*"

> You can also try to adjust the display sensitivity. Go to **Settings > display+touch**, swipe to touch, and switch Touch sensitivity to High.
>
> *-- Microsoft*

[image: *Screenshot of the recent changes on the Settings app*]

Comment: how to switch Touch sensitivity to High. ? where is that settings ?

Comment: Saw your edit, there is no Settings > display+touch , either touch or display , but I couldn't find the exact display sensitive settings.

Comment: touch settings have changed in windows-10, [see this](http://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/larger/public/field/image/2015/11/windows-10-mobile-touch.jpg).

Comment: Yes, and on top of that there were recent changes on the Fast Ring update... I used the Microsoft page, should be the best source, did you make it?

Comment: I added some extra images to improve my answer, hope it helps ;)

Comment: double tap does not work..!! but this was a nice answer anyway for future reference.

Comment: I had a Lumia 925 with WM10 back in January/February and I always used this feature, can someone confirm that there is a bug in this newer software versions (I can still use it on my Lumia 930)? because it can also be a hardware problem...

Comment: Also, did you make your timeout settings to never?

Comment: No, there is no never , only 5 mins

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the screen to never turn off, such an option is only available in interop unlocked phones. tutorials are available on winphonehub.org . but, i seriously recommend you to not do such things as it might damage your device.

Comment: No, they are available in majority of the normal Lumia phones.

Answer (score -1):

In your case (no Tap to turn on and no never option) you need an advanced but not big or complicated app which doing like as game app that make your phone busy on screen.